# Why are there these orange highlights for parameters in Visual Studios java? How can I toggle them off?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[the orange highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVoC5.png)

I thought it was just find so I tried to click on them but that does nothing.

Comment: Other IDEs also have this feature like IntelliJ IDEA. It shows the parameter names as tip. Orange market however is even for a Dutch a bit much.

Comment: @JoopEggen it's their colour theme. looks like they're using a high-contrast theme, where "a bit much" is kind of by design.